# "Invalid command name "W"' while runing tcl script

Tags: tcl, modelsim, invalid-argument

I was making some GUI at TCL in ModelSim, but when i run that it causes some STRANGE error

```
# invalid command name "W"
#     while executing
# "$w nearest $y"
#     (procedure "ListSelectEnd" line 2)
```

It was kinda odd, because almost similar expression was just before that one. That's the code:

```
global a
proc ScrolledListbox { parent args } {
    frame $parent
    eval {listbox $parent.list \
        -yscrollcommand [list $parent.sy set] \
        -xscrollcommand [list $parent.sx set]} $args
    scrollbar $parent.sx -orient horizontal \
        -command [list $parent.list xview]
    scrollbar $parent.sy -orient vertical \
        -command [list $parent.list yview]
    pack $parent.sx -side bottom -fill x
    pack $parent.sy -side right -fill y
    pack $parent.list -side left -fill both -expand true
    return $parent.list
}
#-------------------------------------------
proc ListSelect { parent choices } {
    global a
    frame $parent
    ScrolledListbox $parent.choices -width 20 -height 5 \
        -setgrid true
    ScrolledListbox $parent.picked -width 20 -height 5 \
        -setgrid true
    pack $parent.choices $parent.picked -side left \
        -expand true -fill both
    bind $parent.choices.list <ButtonPress-1> \
        {ListSelectStart %W %y}
    bind $parent.choices.list <ButtonRelease-1> \
    lappend a [ListSelectEnd %W %y .top.f.picked.list]
    eval {$parent.choices.list insert 0} $choices
}
#----------------------------------------
proc ListSelectStart { w y } {
    $w select anchor [$w nearest $y]
}
#-----------------------------------------
proc ListSelectEnd { w y list } {
    $w select set anchor [$w nearest $y]
    foreach i [$w curselection] {
        $list insert end [$w get $i]
        lappend listin [$w get $i]
    }
    return $listin
}
#--------------------------------------------
proc tosignal {parent val} {
    global a
    for {set i 0} {$i<[llength $a]} {incr i} {
        force -freeze sim:/chema_tb/m1/[lindex $a $i] $val 0
    }
    run 1000 ns
    destroy $parent
    return 1
}
#------------------------------------------------
proc form {} {
    global a
    toplevel .top 
    set filename signalfile.txt
    set in [open $filename]
    while {[gets $in var]>-1} {
        lappend spisn [lindex $var 0]
    }
    ListSelect .top.f $spisn
    button .top.okb  -text  OK -width 20 -height 2 -font {-size 15 -family Times -weight bold} \
        -fg blue -anchor center  -command {tosignal .top 0 }
    pack .top.f .top.okb -expand true
}
```

I'll be really thankful if you could help me. :)

Comment: As a general hint, it's _much_ easier to debug code if you use normal indentation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with these lines:

```
bind $parent.choices.list <ButtonRelease-1> \
lappend a [ListSelectEnd %W %y .top.f.picked.list]
```

That performs immediate execution of what appears to be a callback, and passes *very* unlikely arguments to `bind` too. I bet what you want is either this:

```
bind $parent.choices.list <ButtonRelease-1> \
    {ListSelectEnd %W %y .top.f.picked.list}
```

or this:

```
bind $parent.choices.list <ButtonRelease-1> {
    ListSelectEnd %W %y .top.f.picked.list
}
```

or this:

```
bind $parent.choices.list <ButtonRelease-1> \
    [list ListSelectEnd %W %y .top.f.picked.list]
```

In this case, it doesn't matter which you use. (The first two are equivalent except for whitespace. The third one is much more useful when you're binding variables in the script, but you're not doing that in this case.)

Comment: Thank you very much! That was helpfull :D

    `bind $parent.choices.list <ButtonRelease-1> \
        {ListSelectEnd %W %y .top.f.picked.list}`
   
But after that new error appeared...

   `# Trace back: can't read "a": no such variable
   #     while executing
    # "llength $a"
    #     (procedure "tosignal" line 3)`

I have no idea why, because `global a` was written just before the cycle :/